# Turkish visa application

Tags: visas, turkey

Turkish visa application states applicant must have round-trip ticket with Turkish Airlines, Pegasus Airlines, Onur Air or Atlasglobal Airlines. Does British airways flight count?

Comment: You must have read it wrong. Why would Turkey force you to use their airlines for a visa? Absolutely not.

Comment: @HankyPanky citizens of certain countries can apply for a single entry eVisa on arrival, but to do so they have to meet certain conditions, including using an airline that has met the required conditions. For now, those are the airlines listed by the OP. The details are on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey)

Comment: The OP doesn’t mention eVisa, so from visa application I assumed normal visa.

Answer (score 1):

Citizens of certain countries can apply for a 'conditional e-visa' or evisa on arrival which carry certain conditions.

If you're a citizen of one of those countries and are applying for such a visa you must use an airline that has established the correct protocols with the Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs. For now, those are only the four airlines you've listed in your question. Flying with British Airways doesn't count.

You can find details on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey)

Be sure you're applying for the right visa.